# Establishing an FTP Connection to an AS400 from C#: Works from CMD but not in code

Tags: c#, cmd, ftp

Forgive me if this is a silly error. I have virtually no experience with CMD and less with executing cmd from inside a C# program. I want to execute an FTP command programmatically with my C# code that prints the file to a PDF. The problem I'm having is that when being asked to log into the AS400, I think my program isn't waiting long enough to establish a connection before it sends the next line, which is the USERNAME. So the next line fails to log in.

If I do this line by line in cmd, it works just fine.

Here's what I have:

This is my directory to get to my destination folder:

```
string StatementString = "\\Varying Directories To User Folder\\Directory with spaces\\Destination";

string ToUserDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
            string StatementPath = ToUserDirectory + StatementString;

StringBuilder shortPath = new StringBuilder(255);

GetShortPathName(StatementPath, shortPath, shortPath.Capacity);   

Process CMDScript = new Process();
var processInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
processInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
processInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

CMDScript.StartInfo = processInfo;
CMDScript.Start();

using (StreamWriter sw = CMDScript.StandardInput)
{
    if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
    {
        //"cd \PathDirectory\ [- C:]
        sw.WriteLine("cd" + shortPath.ToString().Substring(2));

        //Delete Old Files
        sw.WriteLine("del /Q *");

        //Connects to my AS400 using its IP Address (Using Zeroes for this question)
        sw.WriteLine("ftp 000.000.00.00");
        sw.WriteLine("USERNAME");
        sw.WriteLine("PASSWORD");

         //Directory of stuff I want from AS400
         sw.WriteLine("cd /home/reallycoolplacewithstuffIneed");

         //Back to my Directory on my PC
         sw.WriteLine("lcd" + shortPath.ToString().Substring(2));

         //Get the stuff I need
         sw.WriteLine("get statements.csv");

         //Exit the command prompt
         sw.WriteLine("bye");
     }
 }



 CMDScript.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
     Console.WriteLine("output>>" + e.Data);
 CMDScript.BeginOutputReadLine();

 CMDScript.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
     Console.WriteLine("error>>" + e.Data);
 CMDScript.BeginErrorReadLine();

 CMDScript.WaitForExit();

 Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: {0}", CMDScript.ExitCode);
 CMDScript.Close();
```

I hope the question is clear enough. I just need a safe method of logging into the AS400 so I can do my FTP. I'm not sure if I'd need some Wait(1) method to pause my program while the connection is established, or if Users and Passwords are handled differently. So far, everything else seems to be working just fine, just not the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Technet article "How to: Download Files with FTP" at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ms229711(v=vs.90) it contains a C# code snippet.

I tried to edit it to the info you provided in your example.

```
using System; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Net; 
using System.Text; 

namespace Examples.System.Net 
{ 
    public class WebRequestGetExample 
    { 
        public static void Main () 
        { 
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server. 
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://000.000.000.000/home/reallycoolplacewithstuffIneed"); 
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile; 

            // Trying to use your credentials 
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME","PASSWORD"); 

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream(); 
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream); 
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd()); 

            Console.WriteLine("Download Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription); 

            reader.Close(); 
            response.Close();   
        } 
    } 
}
```

Hope that helps.

Take care

Andreas